# How to create texture coordinates for a spritesheet with lwjgl

Tags: java, lwjgl, spritesheet

Using lwjgl and slick-util I've been trying to use certain pieces of a spritesheet as textures. lwjgl uses glTexCoord2f(); to map coordinates to individual vertices, and the coordinates it takes in are normalized (between 1 and 0), so I've been using this code to make the coordinates only use a small piece of the full Texture:

```
glTexCoord2f(0 / 128, 0 / 128); glVertex2f(0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(0 / 128, 8 / 128); glVertex2f(0, 32);
glTexCoord2f(8 / 128, 8 / 128); glVertex2f(32, 32);
glTexCoord2f(8 / 128, 0 / 128); glVertex2f(32, 0);
```

but whenever I used normalized coordinates that are a fraction of the images size I just get a solid square that had 50% alpha.

My question is: what am I doing that's making the texture coordinates screw up? Is there a better way to go about this?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Whats with 8/128?

Comment: 8 is a coordinate and 128 is the texture's width. I'm getting the normalized texture coordinates by dividing the x and y by the width and height of the image. It doesn't seem to be working though :(

Comment: I rolled back your edits, if you have another issue that's unrelated to this one, ask it in a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dividing an integer with an integer: `8 / 128`, which results zero. Change it to floating point division: `8.0f / 128.0f`.

Comment: Yes! That's it! Now I'm getting textures! Thanks for the help (I knew it was something small like that).

Answer (score 1):

3Texture coordinates for a sprite sheet can be obtained simply by using the number of sprites wide and the number of sprites high. It's a simple modulus operation using that information. Something like the following will return the coordinates for a textured quad:

```
public static Vector2f[] calculateUVMapping(int texture, int atlasWidth, int atlasHeight) {
    int textureIndex = texture;

    int u = textureIndex % atlasWidth;
    int v = textureIndex / atlasHeight;

    float xOffset = 1f / atlasWidth;
    float yOffset = 1f / atlasHeight;

    float uOffset = (u * xOffset);
    float vOffset = (v * yOffset);

    Vector2f[] UVList = new Vector2f[4];

    UVList[0] = new Vector2f(uOffset, vOffset); // 0,0
    UVList[1] = new Vector2f(uOffset, vOffset + yOffset); // 0,1
    UVList[2] = new Vector2f(uOffset + xOffset, vOffset + yOffset); // 1,1
    UVList[3] = new Vector2f(uOffset + xOffset, vOffset); // 1,0


    return UVList;
}
```

Where `texture` is the index of the sprite you want, `atlasWidth` is the number of evenly sized sprites in the entire texture width and `atlasHeight` is the number of evenly sized sprites in the entire texture height.

Then you can see the coordinates labeled in the comments, it will return an array of coordinates like: [(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)].

`texture` counts the index from left to right, top to bottom. So for example if I wanted to get the 6th sprite in a atlas that was 5 sprites wide and 10 sprites tall, I would use `calculateUVMapping(6,5,10);` That sprite would be the one in the second column of the second row (because we start at `0`).

Comment: Thanks! I'll use this in for getting the sprite now that I know what I was doing wrong :P